# Footer message that remains at the bottom of the page

Tags: footer

Looking for a footer message solution that remains at the bottom of the page.
In the past, I have tried couple of Footer solutions but in most cases the footer message doesn't appear at the bottom of the page. If the site content is over then immediately the footer would appear.

Thus its not at the bottom of the page.

Solution followed: http://www.eliostruyf.com/sticky-footer-solution-for-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: You need to fix the height of the page for it. :)

Comment: I've always used Elio's solution and never had a problem. The footer is always at the bottom of the page (not the window bottom). Check your master page structure. Can you post your screenshot of the footer?

Comment: Hardik, I cant share the page screenshot as it contains the client`s data and cant be shared due to compliance.

However, trust me its not at the bottom of the page, but at the bottom of windows screen.

Comment: Here is the attachment that shows the footer is above the webpart and placed at the bottom of window screen rather the page bottom.

Image: http://imgur.com/aNR7rRj

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like it's an issue with your CSS and the way you've structured your master page. You're probably missing some clearfix in the main content area. See Elio's result screenshot and match your structure and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Footer is very tricky and I talked to some SP UX experts in this matter and they usually recommend not to go with it or they use Randy Solution here

[Sticky Footers in SharePoint](http://blog.drisgill.com/2013/01/sticky-footers-in-sharepoint.html)

**Note :-** Check also the comments section in his post for more tips

Comment: Guys we are talking the same language now.

I`m currently using the solution by Randy, challenge is that is overlaps the content at the bottom of the page.

Example: If a webpart is at the bottom of the page, then when you scroll down u would see the Footer above the Webpart.
Thus technically its not at the bottom of the page, but at the bottom of the screen of your display and would slide down as slide the page down.

Any suggestion how to make it visible only at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Hardik & Ahmed, any suggestion to get the footer placed at the bottom of the page only following Randy`s solution.

Comment: I `ve added Elio's solution its working fine. However, the links part of my Footer text work on IE browser but not in Chrome. Any clue?